# android driver cannot locate an webElement on android

Tags: android, selenium, iframe, appium, selenium-chromedriver

I use appium to with my andorid app

I see this activity

[image]

and I see it's page source:

```
myDriver.getPageSource() = 
<!DOCTYPE html><!--[if lte IE 8]><html class="oldie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]--><!--[if IE 9]><html class="ie9 card-root"> <![endif]--><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="is-modern card-root js touch csstransitions svg inlinesvg placeholder"><head>
    <title>Cards</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="/dropin/1.5.1/vendor/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/dropin/1.5.1/braintree-dropin.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/dropin/1.5.1/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="inline-frame">
    <div id="container">
    <div class="add-payment-method-view hidden"></div><div class="show-payment-method-view"><div class="payment-method-item card-label">
  <span class="payment-method-icon stick-left visa"></span>
  <span class="payment-method-type">Visa</span>
  <span class="payment-method-description">ending in 15</span>
</div>
<div class="payment-method-action">
  <button class="link link-small" id="choose-payment-method">Change payment method</button>
</div>

</div></div>

    <div class="loader">
      <div class="loader-background"></div>
      <div class="indicator">
        <svg id="loader-svg-icon" width="14px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 28 32" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
          <g id="New-Customer" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
            <g id="Loading" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup" transform="translate(-526.000000, -915.000000)" fill="#FFFFFF">
              <g id="Loading-Indicator" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" transform="translate(468.000000, 862.000000)">
                <g id="Secure" transform="translate(58.000000, 53.000000)" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup">
                <path d="M6,10 L6,7.9998866 C6,3.57774184 9.581722,0 14,0 C18.4092877,0 22,3.58167123 22,7.9998866 L22,10 L18,10 L18,7.9947834 C18,5.78852545 16.2046438,4 14,4 C11.790861,4 10,5.79171562 10,7.9947834 L10,10 L6,10 Z M0.996534824,14 C0.446163838,14 0,14.4449463 0,14.9933977 L0,31.0066023 C0,31.5552407 0.439813137,32 0.996534824,32 L27.0034652,32 C27.5538362,32 28,31.5550537 28,31.0066023 L28,14.9933977 C28,14.4447593 27.5601869,14 27.0034652,14 L0.996534824,14 Z" id="Rectangle-520"/>
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="loader-message">Authenticating...</div>
    </div>

    <div class="cancel-popup">
      <button class="cancel-popup-button">Cancel PayPal Login</button>
    </div>

    <!--[if LT IE  9]><script src="/dropin/1.5.1/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte IE 9]><!--><script src="/dropin/1.5.1/vendor/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->
    <script src="/dropin/1.5.1/braintree-dropin-internal.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var inlineFrame = new braintree.dropin.InlineFrame.Manager({
        container: document.getElementById("container")
      });
      inlineFrame.initialize();
    </script>


</body></html>
```

How can i click on "Add payment" ?
I cannot reach to it via the driver.

It's a webView with an iframe in it

but I have already stepped into the web-view context and the iframe context as well.

here is my try:

```
@Override
public void fillData(ImmutableMap<PaymentFields, String> map) {
    myAD.changeToWebContext();
    myAD.changeToIFrame(By.cssSelector("#braintree > iframe"));

    final WebElement element = myAD.findElement(By.id("choose-payment-method"));
    if (element != null) {
        element.click();
        WebElement element1 = myAD.findElement(By.cssSelector("#container"));
```

Comment: Did you check the screen using chrome://inspect ??